# How to scrape data from PDF file in Python

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, scrape, web-scripting

I want to scrape the data present in 7th page of [this PDF](ftp://ftp.publicdebt.treas.gov/dfi/tfmb/dfifd0717.pdf) and move to dataframe then CSV.

Could you please help on the same?

Answer (score 2):

Install the [`pypdf`](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) package. You can use pypdf.PdfReader() to extract the data from PDF to a string. Then use the csv.writer() in the csv module(in-built) to write it to csv. You have to read more on them